# onclick="document.getElementById('showme')

Tags: magento2.2.6, html, table

I am trying to make this work in Magento, but Magento changes the html and my boss hates it when I want to change anything using cPanel. So I need an option using the dashboard in Magento

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Stock replacement: Bolt in press on bearing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('showme').style.display = 'table-row'; return false;"><li>How To Measure</li></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="showme" style="display: none">
           <td><embed src="https://dutchmanaxles.com/images/ordering/SR_defined_POB.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using Magento 2, I would suggest to use requireJs

```
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Stock replacement: Bolt in press on bearing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><a href="#" id="showEmbed"><li>How To Measure</li></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="showme" style="display: none">
       <td><embed src="https://dutchmanaxles.com/images/ordering/SR_defined_POB.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  require(['jquery'],function($){
    $('#showEmbed').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#showme').toggle();
    })
  })
</script>
```

Ideally I would move JS content to separate JS file and initialize whole functionality via `x-magento-init` script or directly bind JS functionality on element via `data-mage-init` *( both variants are described in Magento DevDocs: [Calling and initializing JavaScript](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html) )*

In case you want to just show embedded content, change jQuery `toggle` function to `show`

Comment: That worked!! Now how can i make the window that opens up longer? right now it is only 149.6px tall? https://dutchmanaxles.com/contact-dutchman-axles.html is where i shoved it for now, but i cant keep it there for very long

Comment: and i cant get it to show on properly on mobile.

Comment: First of all, I could not find code mentioned here on link you've provided. Second of all, your problem will be connected now with HTML rendering and not Magento itself. I guess problem with displaying on mobile is, that you are using HTML tables. About height of embed element, I can't say for sure.

Comment: should i use div rather than tables? can i set it up exactly the way it is now with div?

Comment: From my point of view yes. If you want, you can check lots of articles online which explains problems with table layouts _( [i.e. this one](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/) )_ But keep in mind, if you replace table layout with divs, you will have to add styling. _( divs won't look like table by default )_

Comment: You should remove  `type="text/javascript"` and only use a `<script>...</script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Stock replacement: Bolt in press on bearing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><button onclick="myFunction();">How To Measure</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="showme" style="display: none">
           <td><embed src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" width="100%" height="600px" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert("Hello");
  var x = document.getElementById("showme");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this created the botton, but it didnt work

Comment: Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/1kgscbd9/

Comment: yeah i have the height set to 600px but page just doesn't allow it

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, i prefer the data-mage-init way, like described in Core.

You can use it anywhere in Magento .phtml files :

**/vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/templates/inline.phtml** around **line 30** :

```php
<button class="action action-gift"
        data-mage-init='{"toggleAdvanced": {"selectorsToggleClass":"hidden", "toggleContainers":"#allow-gift-messages-for-order-container"}}'>
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Gift Message') ?></span>
</button>
<div id="allow-gift-messages-for-order-container" class="gift-messages-order hidden">
```